# How is Python itself tested?

Tags: python, testing

How is Python itself tested?  Not, "How do I write unit tests in Python?" but "Where is the compliance suite against which CPython, Pypy, and so on run tests to assert they're Python version-X.Y conformant?"

The python website mentions pythontest.net, but that appears to be just a target for test facilities, not part of or a resource for the compliance suite itself.

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPython source code includes a [test suite](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/test) that is considered to be the compliance suite. This suite is used to test other Python implementations, see for example:

- the [PyPy copy of the suite](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/a0105e0d00dbd0f73d06fc704db704868a6c6ed2/lib-python/2.7/test/?at=default).
- the [Jython copy](https://hg.python.org/jython/file/tip/lib-python/2.7/test)
- the [IronPython test suite](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/tree/ipy-2.7-maint/Languages/IronPython/Tests), which is a subset tuned to what IronPython supports (only a subset of the CPython standard library is included in IronPython)

Comment: The CPython test suite is often installed right along with the standard library (though different distributions may leave it out or package it separately). Try `python -m test` to run it if it's available on your system!

Comment: Which by the way is documented in the [documentation of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html)

Comment: @Blckknght: I linked to the Python 2.7 version, because that's what the 3 big re-implementations support right now. In Python 2.7, you run the suite with `python -m test.regrtest` instead.